# Issue with Camera-to-view hotkey? (ctrl+alt+num0)

Tags: 3d-view, camera, shortcut

I'm having a strange issue where when I add a camera to my scene and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>NUM0</kbd> to set camera to view, the actual view gets shifted over a little bit. Please check out my screenshots below:

1. No camera added yet

[image: No camera added yet]
2. Added camera at world origin/3d cursor

[image: Added camera at world origin/3d cursor]
3. After pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>NUM0</kbd>

[image: After pressing CTRL+ALT+NUM0]
4. Camera location in 3D space is moved

[image: Camera location in 3D space is moved]

This isn't the intended behavior, right? Can anyone replicate this?

Comment: I guess you want the orthographic front view in camera...The camera by default it perspective. Just navigate into camera settings in the properties tab and change it from Perspective to Orthographic then try re aligning your camera

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything is working as correctly to me.

Your original viewport view isn't centered. It may look like that to you because the cube is near the center of your *monitor*, but it's actually down and to the right of the actual viewport itself.

To center your view on an object (or any number of selected objects), press "." on your numpad, *then* align your camera. That should resolve the issue :)